# Fixing creaky stair treads post remodel

Tags: stairs

We had a contractor remodel our staircase. To save money, instead of rebuilding the entire staircase, the contractor pulled off the carpet, trimmed off the nose of the old tread, and installed a red oak tread on top, securing it with construction adhesive and just a couple finish nails to hold in place (installed some fascia trim to hide the old tread). We've been satisfied more or less, however some of the treads are really starting to creak now. I have access to the underside of the staircase and was wondering if it would help to drive around 5-6 3/4" construction screws from the bottom, up through the old stair base (now sub-tread) and into the new oak tread (being careful not to poke through). Would that help with the squeaking? I can't shim anything here from below, because the gap between old tread and new tread is not accessible (blocked by the riser). The only other alternative I can think of is to pry off the new tread, scrape off the old adhesive, and re-glue it down with something stronger? I'm not at the point where I just want to rebuild the darn thing, but anything to help some of squeakiness would be great.

Comment: The type of remodel that was done would have made the rise on the bottom step larger and the rise at the top step smaller by the thickness of the red oak. Has this been noticeable at all in looks or usage of the steps?

Comment: I think you would need a longer screw to penetrate the double thick treads to reach the stringer with proper grip length in the wood.

Comment: @MichaelKaras no not noticeable at all. That's no issue for us

Comment: @r13 good point, might need something more like 1 1/4"